# UITableview cell reinitializing every time in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

All,

I hope most of you know that with ios7 there is not need to do a null check for tableview reuse

```
if (cell == nil) {
```

But unfortunately, because of that the cells are always reinitialized, as we put the code in the same method for initializing values. The problem is only with text fields inside the tableview though.

Let me explain the scenario. I have a table view with multiple rows, and some rows contain multiple text boxes. I populate the textboxes with data from server when the page is loaded. Since the cells are always re-initialized as i explained above, whatever I enter in the field goes away and the server data is re populated once i scroll down and come back to the initial stage. This is because the populating the data code is also in the same place. After fetching a reusable cell it populates the data.

Previously till ios6, we used if(cell==nil) and hence we loaded server data inside the cell and when reusing the cell, this piece of code will never be called.

I have other dirty solutions, but would like to know if someone else has a graceful way of dealing this. Please help.

Comment: You just don't store any data in the table view cell but in the model that fills the table cell. This is always the way it should be done.

Comment: @rckoenes your solution seems right. Do we always need to associate a model with everycell ?

Comment: That is the most common approach, since a `UITableViewCell` is just a view and is reused by iOS. Looking from a MVC standpoint, then yes you should always use a model.

Comment: Seems right. If you put your answer as an 'answer' instead of a comment, i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't store any data in the table view cell but in the model that fills the table cell. This is always the way it should be done.

Looking from the MVC standpoint than the `UITableViewCell` is a view. Since it is reused by iOS you should use a model to the view.

Comment: Do you suggest that whenever we enter something in the text field, it should be persisted in model using the text field's delegate methods?

Comment: That would make sense, since the model is holding the data displayed.

Comment: Wont that become a very complex solution? Isnt this a common problem?Isnt there any good way of doing this?

Comment: You could create something generic to handle the text entry. The complexity is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behavior of UITableView. For performance reasons, cells are reused. Thus, it is your responsibility to populate the views in a Table View Cell every time tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called.

The thing I don't understand from your question - are you making a network call every single time a cell comes into view? If so, cache the results somewhere. Or, if it's a small amount of data, consider just doing it all in one shot at the beginning (still need to be asynchronous though).

One thing I see a lot of developers do is move a lot of code into UITableViewCell subclasses, which sounds like a good idea because it's modular, but makes solutions for problems like this more difficult. Have the Table View Data Source manage the network calls.

If you need some inspiration, look at Apple's LazyTableImages sample.

Comment: No I dont make a network call for every cell. I think you didnt understand my question properly